# QGIS find overall min/max

Tags: qgis, raster, statistics

I have a variety of raster files from the exact same study area including different values (hourly mean radiant temperature). Is it possible to find out the overall min/max values (not each individual one)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Statistics for rasters** tool (in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Geostatistics`).

It will give you `Minimum` and `Maximum` raster, each cell represents the minimum and maximum value across the layers. (There are also `Percentile`, `Arithmetic Mean` etc... if you like).

If you want to have single overall `minimum` or `maximum` value, next step will be **Raster Layer Statistics** tool (in `Processing Toolbox | QGIS - Raster Analysis`). Give  `Minimum` raster from above operation to this tool, then `MIN` value is the overall minimum.